# Session Sharing between two web applications running on the same application pool using InProc Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inproc

I have two MVC web application running in the same application pool of IIS 
 [Attached image of two applications which are InProcSessionState and L which runs under InProcSessionState application pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGr6C.png)

I have tried using **InProc** session to share data between two applications by adding this in Web.Config

```html
<sessionState mode = "InProc" timeout = "60">
</sessionState>
```

In application 1, I have put the username in session and tried to fetch from session 2, but every time I am getting Null while retrieving.

What could be causing this issue ?

[Storing username in session in Application 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6slG.png)

[Retrieving data from the session in Application 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UNQv.png)

Comment: Though both the applications share same application pool, they are still in different appdomains. I think, you should go for "OutProc" session state mode, or think about using some session management platform such as "Redis session"

Comment: We are already using Redis for session management. Since we are facing some issues like session clearance sometimes and also both applications run in same domain, thought of using InProc. So             
" localhost:8123/L and localhost:8123" can't share data using InProc session?